# Mysql Query find part of item

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following item in MYSQL table: 
"Plants vs Zombies FREE" 
when i search for "Zombies" or when i search for "Plants" ,there will be no results.
The Query i'am using:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE %Plants%
```

PHP code:

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE '%" . $val . "' OR `COL 2` LIKE '%" . $val . "%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["COL 1"] . ";" . $row["COL 2"] . ";" . $row["COL 3"] . ";" . $row["COL 4"] . ";" . $row["COL 5"] . ";" . $row["COL 6"] . "<br>";
        }else{
         echo "0 results";}
```

How could i modify the query so i could find "Plants vs Zombies FREE" when i search for any part from it ?

Answer (score 1):

You missed `%`

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE '%" . $val . "%' OR `COL 2` LIKE '%" . $val . "%'";
 .................................................................^
```

Right now, your query only searches for the ones that `COL 1` ends with `$val`  or  `COL 2`  contains `$val`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround it with quotes like this

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE '%Plants%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Using "%" before and after of the value

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE '%$val%' OR `COL 2` LIKE '%$val%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `COL 1` LIKE '%" . $val1 . "' OR `COL 2` LIKE '%" . $val2 . "%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

assign $val1 to 'Plants' and $val2 to 'Zombies'